# ssh: 2 acts like ^w regardless of terminal

Tags: ssh, stty

In my decades of experience of *n?x based OSes, I have never seen this before:
It happens during SSH commands.  Regardless of terminal or terminal emulator, pressing the number 2 within SSH sends a `^W` (ie: `stty werase`).  Troublesome since I need to do `^V` prior to the pressing 2.  **Note:** this occurs within a password prompt and/or with the SSH session.

This behavior does not occur outside of SSH and `^W` behaves as it should both inside and outside of SSH.

Has anyone ever seen this behavior?

**Update #1** `stty -a` (outside of SSH) shows my `werase` as `2`.  I am not sure when or where that was set.

Comment: do you mean that if you run `cat` inside the ssh session, and type `foo bar`, pressing `2` will erase the `bar`?

Comment: Yes, if I typed out the command were to be `cat foo bar2` prior to pressing `enter`, it would result in `cat foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*facepalm*  I seem to have a mistake in a startup file:
`stty werase 2> /dev/null`

Comment: still confusing as to why pressing `2` at any other time (outside of SSH) does not affect the output.  Typing `bzip2` does not kill the entire word.

Comment: this is because the shells line-editor (eg. readline) implements the werase itself. Try my trick with cat outside the ssh and it should "work" `cat<Enter>foo bar2`.

Comment: And I guess you are either using csh or tcsh as your shell or have a space between `2` and `>`: `stty werase 2 >/dev/null`.

Comment: Yes, it is applied to tcsh, but no space between the `2` and the `>`

Comment: `cat<ENTER>foo bar2` resulting in `bar` getting deleted.

Comment: tcsh does not support the `2>/dev/null` to redirect only the stderr. One (awkward) way to redirect only the stderr to `/dev/null` in csh is `(command >/dev/tty) >& /dev/null`.

Comment: Correct, hence the mistake.  Seems I duplicated that line, in part, from my bash startup.  I also noticed that, under tcsh, `stty` was incomplete.  It should have been written out as `stty werase ^V^W` so that the resulting output would be `stty werase ^W`

Comment: No, stty knows how to interpret the caret notation itself: you can write just `stty werase '^W'` with `^` and `W`.